# Cloud Firestore - QuerySnapshot.toObjects Throws Null Pointer Exception

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I've stumbled upon a strange problem. I'm trying to accomplish a simple thing - convert everything from a QuerySnapshot to a collection of a certain type.

```
fun createReminder(reminder: Reminder) = 
    remindersCollectionRef.document("${reminder.taskId}").set(reminder)

fun tryRemoveReminder(taskId: Int) = 
    remindersCollectionRef.document("$taskId").delete()

fun getReminders(onComplete: (List<Reminder>) -> Unit) {
    remindersCollectionRef.get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { querySnapshot ->
            if (!querySnapshot.isEmpty)
                 onComplete(querySnapshot.toObjects(Reminder::class.java))
            }
        }
```

The problem is in the getReminders function. I know that there is one reminder in the collection. It is also 100% of type Reminder and as you can see I already check if querySnapshot is not empty. Still, I get a null pointer exception when I call toObjects.

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[])' on a null object reference
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzevb$zza.zza(Unknown Source:57)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzevb.zza(Unknown Source:1025)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzevb.zza(Unknown Source:2)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.toObject(Unknown Source:10)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot.toObjects(Unknown Source:27)
at com.mypackage.util.FirestoreUtil$Companion$getReminders$1.onSuccess(FirestoreUtil.kt:131)
at com.mypackage.util.FirestoreUtil$Companion$getReminders$1.onSuccess(FirestoreUtil.kt:18)
at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source:27)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Reminder class:

```
data class Reminder(val taskDocRef: DocumentReference, val taskId: Int)
```

This issue seems really strange to me. I will appreciate your help :)

Comment: Can you post the stack trace you are getting? It seems odd that you can test for empty and then get an NPE right away. Perhaps something inside the `toObjects` function?

Comment: @Todd I just added the stack trace.

Comment: Sorry, one more thing. Can we get the code for Reminder?

Comment: @Todd Sure. Sorry for not adding it sooner.

Comment: Try creating that as a class with a default (zero argument) constructor.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting that! It's strange that a zero argument constructor solves it because I also have a class Task which doesn't have one. I'm calling `toObject(Task::class.java)` on DocumentReference (not CollectionReference) and there's no problem with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you carefully read documentation for Cloud Firestore query requirements for mapping Custom objects [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data), there will be notice:

> Important: Each custom class must have a public constructor that takes
>   no arguments. In addition, the class must include a public getter for
>   each property.

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure that you change the rules in the Firestore

For rules go to https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#secure_your_data and copy the rules of testmode and paste them in the firestore rules

It take 10 minutes to change the rules.So run the app again after 10 minutes